# How to make twitter bootstrap buttons bigger?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am learning html, css and twitter bootstrap as I go along.

```
  <div id="button" style=" position:absolute;top:450px; left:350px;">
        <p>
        <a href="https://docs.google.com/forms/d/1Exo4u2iRpChj- 
           Wg9K5HxteMeoVE1uee0fQKBWiuYYiw/viewform?pli=1" class="btn btn-primary btn-  
           large">Search
        </a>
    </p>
    </div>
```

I want to increase the size of the font of this button and hence make it bigger. Could someone help me with this please?

Thanks!

Answer (score 65, accepted):

here are the sizes bootstrap offers right out of the box.

```
.btn-large
.btn-small
.btn-mini
```

read more about it [here](http://twitter.github.io/bootstrap/base-css.html#buttons)

it's under `Button sizes`

**Edit:**

or you could make your own:

```
.btn-xlarge {
    padding: 18px 28px;
    font-size: 22px; //change this to your desired size
    line-height: normal;
    -webkit-border-radius: 8px;
       -moz-border-radius: 8px;
            border-radius: 8px;
}
```

Source located [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112200/resizing-buttons-in-twitter-boostrap)

Comment: However, if i raise the padding & font, in mobile view then will overlap screen

Answer (score 75):

This has changed in Bootstrap 3.

Now it is .btn-lg, .btn-sm, or .btn-xs

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.4/css/

Answer (score 10):

This has changed again in Bootstrap 4.

Now there is only `.btn-lg` and `.btn-sm`

https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/#sizes