# Bootstrap, how to change height of buttons in navbar?

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, navbar

a am using the bootstrap navbar. 
Since I added a brand logo the navbar itself is heigher than the buttons in the navbar. How can I increase height of the buttons to fit to the height of the navbar? I appreciate your help!

Below you will find an excerpt of my code

https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16265/#&togetherjs=1vljfIHdrL

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/4/4c/ZDF_logo_1992-2001.png/120px-ZDF_logo_1992-2001.png" alt="Logo" height="80px"></a>
    </div>

    <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active"><a href="#">Link <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
        <div class="form-group">
          <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
      </form>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">
          <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
          <ul class="dropdown-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
            <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
            <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
  </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

Regards
Marina

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow, could you create a jsfiddle of your code ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Resizing buttons in Twitter-Bootstrap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13112200/resizing-buttons-in-twitter-bootstrap)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Bootstrap, the buttons in the navbar have their size set by `padding`. The default padding value for `.navbar-brand` and the navbar buttons are:

```
padding: 15px 15px;
```

If you want to increase the height of these buttons, you can override the default styling:

```
.navbar-brand, .nav > li > a {
  padding: 30px 15px;
}
```

[Here is your Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/16271/) updated to depict the changes.

Comment: Hi Drew, I thank you very much! This is what I am looking for!